# Reading a file in Mac OSX Sandbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder, appstore-sandbox

I am trying to read a file in sandbox mode outside application sandbox. I went through this [objColumnist](http://objcolumnist.com/2012/05/21/security-scoped-file-url-bookmarks/) post, and definitely Apple's `App Sandbox Design Guide` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16).

Documentation clearly states that you need a `NSOpenPanel` or `NSSavePanel` to read/write files in `Security-Scoped Bookmarks`.

> If your app employs a download or processing folder that is outside of the app container, obtain initial access by presenting an NSOpenPanel dialog to obtain the user’s intent to use a specific folder

My use case is a bit different, I want to read a file from finder. Like when user triggers some hotkey from finder, i will get the selection from finder (using scripting bridge to get file selection) and then read that file. Hence i can not create a `Security-Scoped Bookmarks`.

So is there an alternative way to read a bookmark file. Or is there other way other than scripting bridge to get finder selection that fits in with app sandbox as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get this done: Use NSService to publish a File-Service in the Finder > Services Menu
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000850-BCIDHJJA

The user selects a file in the Finder, calls the service thru either the context menu, a shortcut/hotkey or the Finder menu. You'll receive a security scoped bookmark on which you then can access the file.

The way with AppleScript will not be allowed in the Mac App Store as you cannot get an entitlement to script Finder.

Comment: Looks interesting, will give it a try

Comment: This is pretty much everything what i was looking for, but it can only be triggered by the shortcut set by NSKeyEquivalent in info.plist or has been set in "System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts". Is there a way i can trigger service with some global shortcut that i have registered. Like I want users to set/update shortcuts in My Application's Preferences.

Comment: You're probably better off asking this in a new question. As far as I know you can't use CGEvent Services in a sandboxed environment to tap into global shortcuts: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Except for Downloads, Pictures, Movies and Music, you definitely need the user's consent to read a file.

Your app can register to read certain types of file using UTI's and then you can implement the appropriate app delegate method to open a file that the user double clicks in the finder. Like how pages opens when the user double clicks a pages document.

Apart from that, (unless you don't use sandboxing) your app is restricted for security reasons. The only way through the sandbox is by using powerbox, which is handled by the NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel transparently and cannot be accessed directly by you, the developer.